# Whats the best way to pass values from an html page to a java class?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I have a project that needs to be changed..
right now i have a web page that posts to a jsp that calls a servlet that calls a "backend" using Tomcat.

I need to get take Tomcat off the scene.

What i want is when i POST,  it calls directly the "backend"

Any suggestions on how can i accomplished that?

Thanks
Rev

Comment: Thanks for your responses , just realized that i cannot POST without a servlet container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu need a servlet container to manage the logic that will allow you to accept a POST request.

Answer (score 4):

Thus, you want to invoke a servlet class *without* using an servlet container like Tomcat?

You can't do that. Period.

If you elaborate in more detail *why* you need to do this (I really can't imagine of a legitimate reason by the way), we may give more suggestions *how* to solve/workaround the particular issue.

**Update**: since you tagged `homework`, is the reason maybe that you "accidently" created a JSP page and a Java class while your school doesn't have Tomcat running as sorta demo server, but just Apache+PHP or so instead? If so, then you'll really need to convert/translate to the suitable language. Don't waste time figuring ways to use JSP/Java without a Java Servlet Container at any way, there simply isn't a way. At least, not a "normal" way.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove the servlet container if you want to use java.

Maybe you can rewrite the whole page in php and only use an apache web server ? You'll have to call directly you're DB or services. If you want to use your back-end application you'll have to keep tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using servlet then you can not take tomcat off from the scene and you are telling you have a web page then you should need any servlet container.
**If you want tomcat off from the scene then you can go for **jetty** or **resin****

Comment: Both are also servlet containers. I understood that he don't want to use a servlet container at all.

Comment: hi Balus he didnt inform he does not want any servlet container.. he just does not want tomcat

Comment: He literally said: *What i want is when i POST, it calls directly the "backend"*. Seems pretty clear to me. BTW: I didn't downvote you :)